# C# - Calling functions from a different class

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, events, static

I have 4 classes

Comment Class:

```
public class comment
    {
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string Comment { get; set; }

        public comment(string _username, string _comment)
        {
            this.Username = _username;
            this.Comment = _comment;
        } 
    }
```

Pin Class:

```
   public class Pin : PhoneApplicationPage

        public List<comment> Comment_List;        

    public Pin(){

        this.Comment_List = new List<comment>();
    }
}
```

Message Page:

```
public partial class MessagePage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
   Pin _Pin;

   public MessagePage(Pin _pin)
 {        
    this._Pin = _pin;
 }

 public void Refresh()
 {
   this.textbox1.Text = "";
   foreach (comment c in this._Pin.List)
   {
    this.textbox1.Text += c.Username;
   }

  }

public void function()
{
     //Call static function in another class to download new pin info
}
```

The static function then updates a static class called PinList().

I have an event triggered in PinList() class when Its static List of Pins is updated, How to i address the object that is the current MessagePage to to call a function to update the textbox with the new values in Pin.comments.

i.e. i Have:

```
public class PinList
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Pin> list;
        public static ObservableCollection<Pin> MainPinList = new ObservableCollection<Pin>();
        public event PropertyChangingEventHandler PropertyChanged;

public PinList()
        {
            list = new ObservableCollection<Pin>();
            list.CollectionChanged += listChanged;            

            ((INotifyPropertyChanged)list).PropertyChanged += new PropertyChangedEventHandler(list_Property_Changed);

        }


    private void list_Property_Changed(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs args)
            {
                  //Need to call
                  //MessagePage.Refresh();
            }
```

Comment: Could you add the Pinlist class code here... it seems your problem lies in there.

Comment: @Mike Trusov - I've updated it with the head of the PinList class

Comment: How are pins in pinlist related to pins in messagepages? Is there a list of messagepages anywhere which can be accessed from pinlist?

Comment: The static 'MainPinList' is a list of Pin objects, each pin object has a MessagePage. The static function that updates a pins comments adds it to the static 'MainPinList'. I have a non-static event when a Pins comments change in the 'MainPinList' that is called 'list_Property_Changed'. I somehow need to address the MessagePage that that pin relates to.

Comment: If the MessagePage and MainPinList both have a reference to the same Pin object - updating it in one place is the same as updating it in the other. The issue you're describing is how to get your UI to react to it and display the changes, yes?

Comment: You say "each pin object has a MessagePage" however your code says "each messagepage has a pin" (I'm talking about class definitions above). If each pin indeed had a messagepage member, then you could do this inside your event: ((Pin)sender).MessagePage.Refresh(), however the way your classes are set up, you have to iterate though all existing MessagePages inside the event, and find one with Pin that matches the sender, and then call Refresh for that MessagePage.

Comment: @McAden - Yes, sorry its difficult to describe. Sinse that i already have an event that triggers on the comment changing in PinList() can i call the update function or will i have to rework my classes with 'ObservableCollection's to trigger an event in MessagePage().

Comment: I've updated my answer based on the information you've given. It shows how to make a UI that responds to changing data and how to simplify your model to be more maintainable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the code you've got and the way you've worded it it sounds like you're trying to access `MessagePage` statically as if it was a singleton but there's not a single static Property anything there. If you're dead-set on doing it that way you'll need to declare a static instance of `MessagePage`.

I would recommend, however, that you simply bind an `ItemsControl` of some sort to react to the `Pin.Comment_List` and make Comment_List an `ObservableCollection<comment>` instead of a `List<comment>` and make sure the comment class implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` - then the UI will take care of its own updates. It looks like what you're doing is trying to reinvent the wheel.

**Edit: Based on your comments**

```
public class Comment : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string username;
    private string comment;

    public comment(string _username, string _comment)
    {
        this.Username = _username;
        this.Comment = _comment;
    }                 

    public string Username
    {
        get
        {
            return username;
        }

        set
        {
            if(value != username)
            {
                username = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Username");
            }
        }
    }                   

    public string Comment
    {
        get
        {
            return comment;
        }

        set
        {
            if(value != comment)
            {
                comment= value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Comment");
            }
        }
    }       

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }
    }
}
```

Pin Class:

```
public class Pin
{
    private readonly ObservableCollection<Comment> commentList = new ObservableCollection<Comment>();        

    public ObservableCollection<Comment> CommentList
    {
        get
        {
            return commentList;
        }
    }
}
```

Message Page:

```
public partial class MessagePage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    private readonly Pin pin;

    public MessagePage(Pin _pin)
    {        
        this.pin = _pin;
    }

    public Pin Pin
    {
        get
        {
            return pin;
        }
    }
```

And your data source

```
public class PinList
{
    public ObservableCollection<Pin> list;
    public static ObservableCollection<Pin> MainPinList = new ObservableCollection<Pin>();

    public void Refresh()
    {
         // Here you update the comments list of each of your Pins - The comment
         //     list is an ObservableCollection so your display will automatically
         //     update itself. If you have to change an existing comment due to
         //     an edit or something that will automatically update as well since
         //     we've implemented INotifyPropertyChanged
    }
}
```

Displaying a Pin's comments would look something like this as long as you implemented `INotifyPropertyChanged` on comment and changed Comment_List to an `ObservableCollection<comment>`. All you would need to do in order to update the messages is add any new messages to that pin's Comments_List and the UI will react without you having to do anything in singleton or subscribe to a bunch of events.

```
<ItemsControl DataContext={Binding Pin} ItemsSource="{Binding CommentList}"">
  <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <StackPanel Margin="0 0 0 10">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Username, StringFormat='{0} said:'}" FontWeight="Bold" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Comment}" />
      </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Under Silverlight 4.0 'ItemTemplate' doesn't support 'StackPanel'.

Comment: Oops, surround that in a `<DataTemplate>` - updating the code now.

Comment: Hey there still a problem with the xaml, here is my xaml http://pastebin.com/rJ2F7xci . I've never used it before, im getting the error: "The property 'System.Windows.Controls.Panel.Children' is set more than once. [Line: 51 Position: 63]"

Comment: I think it's getting confused because you're setting `<Grid.Background>` right in the middle of the grid's content. Move it to either before or after all the other stuff. Additionally setting the datacontext and itemssource the way you have will effectively try to make the ItemsSource be `ThePin.comment.Pin.comment` which I don't think is what you mean to do there and I didn't mention it because it's DataBinding basics but you'll need to set the DataContext of that entire PhoneApplicationPage at some point even if it's in code-behind to itself or moving the pin info into a viewmodel.